# Jquery Height-Based Truncate Solution?

Tags: jquery, css, text, height, truncate

I have a project where I need to layout a newspaper like layout with columns but the columns must be a specific height (can at least extend a very little if need be) but holds dynamic content. I need to cut the text, after a sentence ends (a period) even if that means it extends slightly past the limit. I have tried to find back-end solutions to this (as well as attempted my own), css solutions and tricks (overflow:hidden looked horrible) and other tricks here and there but cannot seem to come up with a solution.

Was wondering if there were any height based truncate libraries for JQuery that anyone knew about that preserved until the end of a sentence.

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

This might be what you're looking for:

http://tpgblog.com/2009/12/21/threedots-the-jquery-ellipsis-plugin/

Comment: This almost seems to be what I need except for two things. I don't need to use the ellipsis and want it to finish the sentence it is on. Sort of how it wont finish in the middle of a word but make it to where it doesnt finish in the middle of a sentence. Is this even possible?

Comment: three dots does not support the latest versions of jQuery.  Try http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/ instead.